# Dataframe replace could not replace the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the outlier data by min/max in the sample, but the dataframe.replace doesn't work.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({"value": data.price.values.ravel()},index = data.major_axis.ravel())
result = df.pct_change() 

threshold = np.std(result.value) * 3

maxoutlier = result[result.value > threshold]
minoutlier = result[result.value < -threshold]

minresult = result.ix[result[abs(result.value) < threshold].idxmin()] 
maxresult = result.ix[result[abs(result.value) < threshold].idxmax()] 

result.value.replace(result[result.value > threshold].value, maxresult.value)
result.value.replace(result[result.value < -threshold].value, minresult.value)
```

both result[result.value > threshold].value and maxresult.value have the same type : dataframe. But, I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Thanks for help.

the variable result is a dataframe, for example,

```
               value
2013-08-19       NaN
2013-08-20 -0.013342
2013-08-21  0.002654
2013-08-22  0.001073
2013-08-23 -0.003744
2013-08-26  0.003702
2013-08-27 -0.029353
2013-08-28  0.005176
.........

2014-12-29 -0.000702
2014-12-30 -0.011763
2014-12-31 -0.019453

[346 rows x 1 columns]
```

maxoutlier is also dataframe, for example,

```
               value
2013-09-23  0.051114
2014-04-24  0.082200
```

maxresult is the same, for example,

```
               value
2013-12-23  0.039175
```

so my objective is to replace the maxoutlier by the maxresult.

Comment: btw, `replace` is for replacing strings, not for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure b/c I can't quite recreate what you have there, but maybe you want `result.loc[ result.value > threshold, 'value' ] = maxresult.value`?  I'm not sure how good this approach will be though.  What's a little hard for me to figure out is what the dimensions are going to be of things here (data dependent).  E.g. is `minresult` guaranteed to be a row (series)?  Or could it be empty or a more than one row?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With result.loc[ result.value > threshold, 'value' ] = maxresult.value, the value of result is replace by NaN rather than the value I want.